# Difference of var=1 and var = 1

Tags: equals, equals-operator

How does var=1 actually differ from var = 1? and in what languages do these differences really matter or doesn't matter?

Comment: In the first one, there are no spaces around the equals sign, and in the second there are? Without knowing what language you're talking about, this question makes no sense. In some white space is significant, and in others it's not. In some languages, the single `=` is an assignment operator, and in others it's equality (and in some, it's both depending on context).

Comment: I upvoted the question simply because I both enjoyed reading the other answers and I enjoyed writing mine :-)

Answer (score 4):

In brainfuck, both are ignored as comments.

In sh, `var=1` sets `var` to `1` while `var = 1` tries to run the program `var` with the arguments `=` and `1`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in `bash` for one:

```
var = 1
```

tries to run the `var` program with the `=` and `1` parameters, while:

```
var=1
```

sets `var` to `1`. There's even another variant:

```
var= 1
```

which temporarily sets `var` to the empty string and tries to run the `1` program (`var` is restored to its original value after the run).

And, for completeness:

```
var =1
```

which tries to run the `var` program with the single argument `=1`.

Comment: FORTRAN had the EQ and EQV operators... but one could not simply write 'x EQ y' because (in fortran) white space is ignored AND case is ignored.  So 'x EQ y' would become XEQY.  To get around this (something like) stropping was implemented [c.f. stropping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stropping_%28programming%29#Other_languages) where these operators were implemented as 'x.EQ.y' and 'a.EQV.b'

Answer (score 1):

Read from:

[link1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Computer_languages)
[link2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language)

Runs of whitespace (beyond a first whitespace character) occurring within source code written in computer programming languages are generally ignored; such languages are free-form

In computer programming, a free-form language is a programming language in which the positioning of characters on the page in program text is insignificant. Program text does not need to be placed in specific columns as on old punched card systems, and frequently ends of lines are insignificant. Whitespace characters are used only to delimit tokens, and have no other significance.

Most free-form languages descend from ALGOL, including C, Pascal, and Perl. Lisp languages are free-form, although they do not descend from ALGOL. REXX is mostly free-form, though in some cases whitespace characters are concatenation operators. SQL, though not a full programming language, is also free-form.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, '=' means 'assign' in most programming languages.(The compiler just ignores the blank)

'==' and '===' could be different in some places, such as javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Note: In some languages `var`  itself would be problematic.  In C# , for instance, it is a reserved keyword.  So maybe `x = 1` would be a better example. Also '=' is an assignment operator in some languages and an equality check operator in others.  Instead of worrying about such issues, I have concentrated on the different schools of lexical processing.

My penny's worth:

- In most programming languages of the Algol tradition (including C and its descendants) such whitespace would not make a difference.  Such languages allow eliminating whitespaces without syntactic (or semantic effect) effect as long as doing so does not allow one of the multysymbol predefined operators to be formed: so `` `3+4 `` is the same as `3 + 4` and `x++-5` is the same as `x ++ - 5` but not the same as `x + + - 5`.
- There are languages such as SML in which any sequence of (non-alphanumeric) symbols uninterrupted by whitespace is a valid identifier: in such languages `3+4` is the same as `3 + 4` but `x++-4`  (`x ++- 4') is not the same as`x++ - 4'.
- There are languages in which even something like `3+4` would be treated as a single token i.e. as something syntactically different that `3 + 4`.
- Early versions of FORTRAN had an interesting approach which has gathered criticism and served as the basis of the crushed spacecraft bug story. (More on that below).
- Finally, some languages, such as Miranda, Haskell and CoffeeScript, follow the ISWIM tradition and make indentation syntactically significant.

---

An example of a language that is notorious for its treatment of whitespace is Fortran (although most criticisms apply to the earlier versions of the language; later versions are more like Algol in this respect).

One of the interesting stories is that of the bug that caused a rocket (a space shuttle in the version I heard) to malfunction because FORTRAN ignores spaces and so  `DO 10 I = 1.100` (which should have been `DO 10 I = 1,100`  -- DO is the FORTRAN equivalent of what is in other languages a `for` loop) was parsed as an assignment of the value `100` to the variable `DO 10 I`.

> The line of FORTRAN code  `DO 10 I = 1.100`
>
> apparently did indeed occur. The compiler apparently did what it was
>   supposed to do, ignoring white space and implicitly declaring and then
>   assigning DO10I. Remarkably, the program was actually tested before
>   use. The error was detected, thereby saving a rocket but ruining a
>   future factoid. The demise of the rocket has been widely reported and
>   has become part of programmer folklore.

Source of the quotation:

http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/cyc/p/fbug.htm

---

The topic of whitespace in different programming languages can be quite interesting:

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SyntacticallySignificantWhitespaceConsideredHarmful

Quotes taken from this quite interesting and funny (in a geeky kind of way) source:

> One must wonder why whitespace is always used as a delimiter. By using
>   whitespace as a delimiter, it prevents users from just including
>   spaces in their names, resulting in the CamelCase and
>   EmbeddedUnderscore holy war. Consider that, in C, spaces are only used
>   for type/scope information. If the language had opted for a more
>   pascal-like approach of using colons, then the whole HolyWar could've been avoided. While
>
> global, const, string: null pointer exception message = "A null pointer exception has occurred"
>
> might look foreign to our eyes, it would have avoided some nasty style
>   problems. Especially since space-delimiting seems to have propagated
>   throughout Unix, making compatibility with win32 (that has no qualms
>   about spaces in filenames, SQL tables, etc.) a hassle.
>
> In many programming languages (C, C++, Lisp, Java, Forth, ... etc., as
>   well as HTML, ...), the presence or absence of whitespace is
>   syntactically significant (otherwise "foo bar" would mean the same
>   thing as "foobar") (token separator). (LISP uses spaces to separate
>   items in lists ... while other languages often use commas.) However,
>   the various flavors of whitespace (tab, spacebar, return, newline,
>   CR/LF) and various amounts of space are all treated identically as
>   "some whitespace". One space, three spaces, 2 linefeeds, a tab - no
>   significant difference between them.